# How to list running screen sessions?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, gnu-screen

I have a bunch of servers, on which I run experiments using `screen`. The procedure is the following :

1. `ssh` to server XXX
2. launch `screen`
3. start experiments in a few tabs
4. detach `screen`
5. disconnect from the server

While the experiments are running, I can easily find on which servers they are by `ssh`ing to all servers and listing my running processes (using `top` or `ps`).

However, once the experiments are finished, how could I find on which servers I have a screen session opened (so that I can have a look at the output, relaunch them, etc.) ?

PS: my experiments do print their output to files, too... but this is not the point of my question.

Answer (score 539, accepted):

To list all of the screen sessions for a user, run the following command as that user:

```
screen -ls
```

To see all screen sessions on a specific machine you can do:

```
ls -laR /var/run/screen/
```

I get this on my machine:

```
gentle ~ # ls -laR /var/run/screen/

/var/run/screen/:
total 1
drwxrwxr-x  4 root utmp   96 Mar  1  2005 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  840 Feb  1 03:10 ..
drwx------  2 josh users  88 Jan 13 11:33 S-josh
drwx------  2 root root   48 Feb 11 10:50 S-root

/var/run/screen/S-josh:
total 0
drwx------ 2 josh users 88 Jan 13 11:33 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 root utmp  96 Mar  1  2005 ..
prwx------ 1 josh users  0 Feb 11 10:41 12931.pts-0.gentle

/var/run/screen/S-root:
total 0
drwx------ 2 root root 48 Feb 11 10:50 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 root utmp 96 Mar  1  2005 ..
```

This is a rather brilliantly Unixy use of Unix Sockets wrapped in filesystem permissions to handle security, state, and streams.

Comment: I wonder why this answer, one that answered the question perfectly, got a downvote...

Comment: Alternatively if you're wanting to get a specific screen based on a naming convention you can grep the result. `ls -R /var/run/screen/S-root/ | grep "NamingConvention"`. Screens save in the `<pid>.<screen_name>` format. This is useful for bash scripts. So if you have a screen with name `0000.NamingConvention` it'll literally just return the name of the screens you're looking for in an easy to parse format.

Answer (score 35):

**Simple guide to remember...**

`screen` - To create a screen

`screen -list` - List all the detached (running) screens with their screen IDs.

[image]
in this picture -

> 6764.pts-1.v1091330

is a screen ID.

`screen -x [screen id]` - Connect / Attach to a specific running screen.

`Ctrl + D` - while in a screen to Terminate / Stop a screen from running.

`Ctrl + A, Then press D` - while in a screen to detach from screen without disturbing it.

`killall screen` - Detach or terminate all screens.

Answer (score 24):

The command **screen -list** may be what you want.

See the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)

Answer (score 14):

While joshperry's answer is correct, I find very annoying that it does not tell you the screen name (the one you set with -t option), that is actually what you use to identify a session.
(not his fault, of course, that's a screen's flaw)

That's why I instead use a script such as this: `ps auxw|grep -i screen|grep -v grep`

Comment: Take a look at the -S option. The value provided is stored in the unix socket filename and is visible in `ls` output. If you need, you can keep the -t option as well.

Comment: The -S option is great, as it also lets you resume by that session name: `screen -rd <sessionname>`

Comment: grep knows regular expressions:  ps auxw|grep -i [s]creen

Answer (score 13):

I'm not really sure of your question, but if all you really want is list currently opened screen session, try:

```
screen -ls
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 For windows system

 Open putty 
 then login in server
```

If you want to see screen in Console then you have to write command

```
 Screen -ls
```

if you have to access the screen then you have to use below command

```
 screen -x screen id
```

Write `PWD` in command line to check at which folder you are currently

Answer (score 5):

Multiple folks have already pointed that

```
$ screen -ls
```

would list the screen sessions.

Here is another trick that may be useful to you.

If you add the following command as a last line in your **.bashrc**
file on server xxx, then it will automatically reconnect to your
screen session on login.

```
screen -d -r
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: I want to note that you'll have to be logged in as the same user that started the screen, I was worried my screen session was gone, but my file copy was continuing under the user "media".
It may sound logical, but it could save some panic if you oversee it.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases a `screen -RRx $username/` will suffice :)

If you still want to list all screens then put the following
script in your path and call it screen or whatever you like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" != "-ls-all" ]]; then
    exec /usr/bin/screen "$@"
else
    shopt -s nullglob
    screens=(/var/run/screen/S-*/*)
    if (( ${#screens[@]} == 0 )); then
        echo "no screen session found in /var/run/screen"
    else
        echo "${screens[@]#*S-}"
    fi
fi
```

It will behave exactly like screen except for showing all screen sessions,
when giving the option -ls-all as first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below commands.

```
screen -list
```

(or)

```
screen -R
```

Answer (score 0):

> ps x | grep SCREEN

to see what is that screen running in case you used the command

> screen -A -m -d php make_something.php