# How can I list screen sessions by name?

Tags: gnu-screen

With screen, I know I can name & re-attach to sessions by name:

```
screen -S <name>             
screen -r <name>
```

When I execute `screen -ls` I get a list sessions, but the name is not displayed.

How do I see the names of my running sessions?

Comment: What is the issue? My `screen` returns both session id and name when i run `screen -ls`: `There is a screen on: 44376.hello     (Detached)`. What `screen` are you using? Also, this probably belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: Hmmm... then maybe it's my instance?  I get things allong the line of `9116.pts-1.shorewood` with no indication of name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list running screen sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/537942/608639)

Answer (score 4):

When you do `screen -ls`, the session name comes after the TTY number.

Here, I have three screen sessions running with the names `dev1`, `daemons`, and `dbconns`:

```
dev1:~$ screen -ls
Your inventory:
    16101.pts-1.dev1        (Multi, attached)
    30265.daemons   (Multi, attached)
    1691.dbconns    (Multi, attached)
3 Sockets in /tmp/uscreens/S-dstephens.
```