# Checking any screen session active on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

I'm trying discover if any linux screen session is running. Currently, I have the code for only a specific screen by name, but I want discover if any screen session is running. Can you help me?

```
screen -list | grep "SESSİON NAME" && echo "Active Program" || echo "Passive Program"
```

How can I update this code above to match all screens running?

Comment: What is the output of `screen -list` when no sessions are active and when some sessions are active?

Comment: No active: No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-root. // Active: There is a screen on:
        10549.pts-0.database2   (07/13/2019 09:21:20 AM)        (Attached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.

Comment: It's just a example, but I want only discover if there are screen sessions running on my server

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output in your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list running screen sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/537942/608639), [How can I list screen sessions by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3680607/608639), [How to list all users that have terminal sessions, including screen sessions?](https://superuser.com/q/352752/173513), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grep for the proper string:

```
if screen -list | grep "No active:"; then echo "No active Program"; else echo "There is an active Program"; fi
```